# Blank HTML tags

Tags: html, css, tags

Is there a way to have blank HTML tags or in other words, tags that do nothing? For example `<p>` turns the inclosed text into a paragraph, `<b>` turns the text bold, `<div>` creates a box. I'm looking for a tag that has no effect on the text or it's environment. I want this so that I can customise it myself with css or js.

```
I am <x class="FancyText">king</x> of the world.
```

Comment: Why not use a `div` or `span`?

Comment: In HTML5 you can create custom element. but of course that elements make some sense.

Comment: I know that you can force the div or span to do pretty much this, but that's like asking the office manager to go clean the toilet. Yes he can do it, but that's not his job. I'm wondering if there is a tag who has absalutly no job other than to do what you tell it.

Comment: There are lists of HTML5 tags on the Web, so just choose one that isn't used, like "c". But I'm not sure that browsers would all support unknown tags, or that using such nonstandard syntax is worth the possibility of causing confusion. Of course, if you use a macro preprocessor, even a home-grown one, then you can use any symbols you like for any meaning you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no “blank HTML tags”. What come closest are `span` and `div`, but the latter causes line breaks before and after (block rendering) by default and cannot be used in inline context, and the former does not allow any block-level elements inside it.

In practice, you can use a made-up element, like `<foo>...</foo>`, though with some problems on older versions of IE. This is widely regarded as a bad move, though; using `span` or `div`, as appropriate, with a `class` attribute is recommeded.

Consider explaining what you are really trying to achieve, instead of referring to fictional HTML tags expected to do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

For this you'd use either the `div` or `span` element. From the [HTML5 editor's draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/):

> The `div` element has no special meaning at all. It represents its children.
>
> The `span` element doesn't mean anything on its own. ... It represents its children.

The difference between them is that the `div` element should be used where *flow content* is expected (that is to say, sections on a page), whereas the `span` element should be used where *phrasing content* is expected (within text).

In the example you've given, you'd want to use the `span` element:

```
I am <span class="FancyText">king</span> of the world.
```

Comment: In practice it does affect layout. Would rather use `span` or `div` with style `display:inline;`

Comment: `div` is a block level element so depending on what his requirements are a `span` could serve him just as well.

Comment: Op gave an example. Div will break line in that one, if no style is set.

Comment: I've modified the answer to give a justification on why you'd use either.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```html
<div></div>
```

This will do nothing unless you add a class or ID.

Or,

```html
<span>Some text</span>
```

This will do nothing unless you add a class or ID.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use *`<x ...> txt </x>`* as a **place holder**,
than any officially-unused set of chars will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use `<a> ... </a>` for that